# Factoring in terms of Irreducibles

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Factor the polynomial $x^5 + 2x^3 + 3x^2 + 1$ as a product of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

My thoughts: I know what the definition of an irreducible function is but as far as methods to find the correct answer as easy as possible is difficult to understand.

Comment: Please provide some context beyond just a problem statement.

Comment: Have you, for example, checked for the possibility of linear factors?

Comment: first thing I was taught to do is look for roots which can be an easy way to find a irreducible factor.

Comment: Good! Did you find any?

Comment: I got f(3) = 325 which in Z(mod 5) is 0.... so x-3 is one root?

Comment: @D-Man yes, $x-3$ is one factor!

Comment: Correct. That is one linear factor. The rest seems a bit tricky. I stared at the polynomial long and hard, and made the observation: in $\Bbb{Z}_5$ we have $3\cdot2=6=1$, so $3=\frac12$. Thus your polynomial is
$$(x^5+2x^3)+\frac12(x^2+2).$$ Can you use that to make progress?

Comment: Possibly. where do I go with this though?

Comment: I usually dont like working with fractions in an integer set, it makes it a little confusing for me.

Comment: You may be able to "see" a quadratic factor in there. Together with the linear factor you found, you can reach something manageable.

Comment: or could i just divide the big equation by x-1 as a division of polynomials to see what I get and reduce as necessary?

Comment: Ok. Let's put $3$ back in place instead of $1/2$. Then your polynomial is
$$(x^5+2x^3)+3(x^2+2).$$

Comment: Don't use $x-1$. $1$ is not a zero.

Comment: x-3*** excuse me

Comment: Correct. But judging from Charles' answer a quadratic binomial factor may be easier to spot before you factor our $x-3$. Mind you, more often than not it is to your advantage to factor out any known factor. This may be an exception :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Entirely possible. I wanted to show that the problem can be solved 'mechanically', that is, without any special insight. If you see something go with it -- but you can do the problem even if you don't see it.

Comment: Ok. Here's the hint spelled out. The polynomial is equal to (expand the form below)
$$x^3(x^2+2)+3(x^2+2).$$ Factor out this and the known linear factor. You get three factors of degree $1,2,2$. It is easy to check that the quadratic factors are irreducible. Sorry about being a bit cryptic earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You found the linear factors already, leaving the quartic $x^4 + 3x^3 + x^2 + x + 3$. The only possibility is that this factors into two quadratics, thus:
$$
(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)\equiv x^4 + 3x^3 + x^2 + x + 3\pmod5
$$
which you can expand as
$$
x^4+(a+c)x^3+(ac+b+d)x^2+(ad+bc)x+bd\equiv x^4 + 3x^3 + x^2 + x + 3\pmod5
$$
which you can solve as 5 simultaneous equations.

---

The equations are:

$$1\equiv1,\ a+c\equiv3,\ ac+b+d\equiv1,\ ad+bc\equiv1,\ bd\equiv3$$

You can drop the first one, which is already solved:

$$a+c\equiv3,\ ac+b+d\equiv1,\ ad+bc\equiv1,\ bd\equiv3$$

Now there are only two ways to get 3 mod 5 as a product of two numbers: 1 times 3 or 2 times 4 (in either order, of course). Since the problem is symmetrical with respect to switching (a,b) and (c,d), you can assume without loss of generality that $b\le d$ if you like, so there are two possibilities: $b=1,d=3$ and $b=2,d=4$. The first:

$$a+c\equiv3,\ ac+4\equiv1,\ 3a+c\equiv1,\ 3\equiv3$$

and the second:

$$a+c\equiv3,\ ac+1\equiv1,\ 4a+2c\equiv1,\ 3\equiv3$$

Simplifying both you get
$$a+c\equiv3,\ ac\equiv2,\ 3a+c\equiv1$$
and
$$a+c\equiv3,\ ac\equiv0,\ 4a+2c\equiv1$$

Solve both, using $c\equiv3-a$, and see if you can find any solutions.

Comment: can you expand on what you mean by solving 5 equations?

Comment: Ive seen something similar to this where you set the equations equal to the leading coefficient of that degree?

Comment: The coefficients of $x^e$ have to match on both sides, so $bd\equiv3\pmod5$, $ad+bc\equiv1\pmod5$ and so forth.

Comment: im having trouble solving them as embarrassing as that is.....

Comment: I am getting values that doesnt satisy ac +b+d=1.  I keep getting 0=1

Comment: we know that bc is  3,1 or 1,3 respectfully since the cannot be 0

Comment: I've edited my answer to give more hints.